# No Computer Science link in the footer!

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, site-promotion

If you look at the footer of the pages there is a list of SE sites. Under Science we see Mathematics, Cross Validated, Theoretical Computer Science, Physics, MathOverflow, Chemistary, Biology, but not Computer Science! which I think definitely should be there.

Is this an intentional choice or is it a left over from beta days?

Are these sites sorted according to graduation date? 
If so wouldn't it make more sense if they are sorted based on their traffic or number of users?

Comment: [Related question on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257987/what-should-be-in-the-footer).

Answer (score 3):

Under “Science”, the footer now lists
[MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net),
[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com),
[Cross Validated (stats)](https://stats.stackexchange.com),
[Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com),
[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com),
[Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com),
[Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com),
[Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com),
[Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com),
and a link for [more](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science). I think this has been the case for a while.